# Appending rows to dataframe inside dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I am building a `for loop` in which I want to construct a dictionary with 2 dataframes. My loop is creating dataframes with 1 column and 24 rows for each iteration, it does so for 2 separate years and 4 separate columns.

So far, I have managed to save dataframes into 2 keys, and added 4 columns to each dataframe, but only for the first 24 observations. Now, I need to append rows to each dataframe and each column for the duration of the `for loop`.

This means, right now I have 2 keys with the shape `24*4`. But I want to keep appending them so they get the shape `48*4`, `72*4` etc.

The code I have developed looks like this (you can ignore the `for` terms, I only wrote them for this example).

```
for i in year:
    for j in days:
        for column in range(1,5):
            if year == 17544 and s == 1:
                dff_dict['expert_2021']['Price_REG1']=c
            elif year == 17544 and s == 2:
                dff_dict['expert_2021']['Price_REG2']=c
            elif year == 17544 and s == 3:
                dff_dict['expert_2021']['Price_REG3']=c
            elif year == 17544 and s == 4:
                dff_dict['expert_2021']['Price_REG4']=c
            elif year == 26304 and s == 1:
                dff_dict['expert_2022']['Price_REG1']=c
            elif year == 26304 and s == 2:
                dff_dict['expert_2022']['Price_REG2']=c
            elif year == 26304 and s == 3:
                dff_dict['expert_2022']['Price_REG3']=c
            elif year == 26304 and s == 4:
                dff_dict['expert_2022']['Price_REG4']=c
```

I have tried to use `dff_dict['expert_2021']['Price_REG1'].append(c)` to append rows without success, I also tried `concat` but couldn't get it to work.

I am kind of stuck for the moment and would appreciate help.

Thank you.

Edit:

Folliwing comment, the input looks like:

```
    Price_REG4
19       31.27
20       30.07
21       29.86
22       29.32
23       28.42
```

and the expected output like:

```
       Price_REG1  Price_REG2  Price_REG3  Price_REG4
35059       15.08       15.08       15.08       15.08
35060       11.57       11.57       11.57       11.57
35061       14.89       14.89       14.89       14.89
35062        9.94        9.94        9.94        9.94
35063        4.84        4.84        4.84        4.84
```

in 2 separate dataframes.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

not a nice datastructure you are using.
unless you have a strong reason

```
exp21={'Price_REG1':[],'Price_REG2':[],'Price_REG3':[],'Price_REG4':[]}
exp22={'Price_REG1':[],'Price_REG2':[],'Price_REG3':[],'Price_REG4':[]}

dff_dict={'expert_2021':pd.DataFrame(),'expert_2022':pd.DataFrame()}
for i in year:
    for j in days:
        for column in range(1,5):
            if year == 17544 and s == 1:
                exp21['Price_REG1'].append(c)
            elif year == 17544 and s == 2:
                exp21['Price_REG2'].append(c)
            elif year == 17544 and s == 3:
                exp21['Price_REG3'].append(c)
            elif year == 17544 and s == 4:
                exp21['Price_REG4'].append(c)
            elif year == 26304 and s == 1:
                exp22['Price_REG1'].append(c)
            elif year == 26304 and s == 2:
                exp22['Price_REG2'].append(c)
            elif year == 26304 and s == 3:
                exp22['Price_REG3'].append(c)
            elif year == 26304 and s == 4:
                exp22['Price_REG4'].append(c)
for i in exp21:
    dff_dict['expert_2021'][i]=exp21[i]
    dff_dict['expert_2022'][i]=exp22[i]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the data structure? I am getting the input from regressions and this is the best I have managed to structure it.